# Getting the method that threw an exception in UWP

Tags: uwp

In .NET you can use the `Exception.TargetSite` property to get information about the method that threw the exception. The property is not available in UWP apps. Is there any other way to get this information?

Comment: If you are debugging your application and could not catch exception, then you can get this information with Exception Settings Window https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: @AlexejSommer I think he needs it for logging purposes. I need it for the same. It's surprising there are so many things not available in UWP

Comment: @MohibSheth Exactly. I have an existing project which does the logging for a web application and wanted to reuse it.